# What is the use of Fibonacci Heaps and B-Tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Technically I know what is Fibonacci Heaps and B-Tree are. But I want to know the use of the Fibonacci Heaps and B-tree data structure. How much useful these data structure are and where we can find the real use of these data structure? Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid this question is a big-list question and not really fit for Stack Overflow. Check if [programmers.se] might be a better place.

Comment: They are both fruitful sources of questions, and answers, here on SO.   I expect they have other applications too.

Comment: Typically, priority queues (which are queues where we can maintain an ordering on the elements according to some priority in logarithmic time) are implemented as Fibonacci heaps.

Answer (score 2):

B-Tree s are commonly used to store large sets of data which need to be accessed quickly and updated often.

Perhaps the most pervasive use is indexing tables in the commonly used relational databases.

Comment: I think the second point here is at odds with the first.  I think it is relatively unusual for b-trees to be used to store large datasets, rather they are commonly used as indices for large datasets.

Comment: @Mark -- if you are "rolling your own" its often easier to dump all your data in the b-tree structure rather than having a pointer to another store which you must maintain separately :-).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about fibonacci heaps but a b-tree is often used in database indexing and is good for ranged queries. I will try to find something on fib heaps
Edit: it seems like fibonacci heaps are basically just more optimized heaps. Heaps are very good for finding min max and median elements. Heaps are also used to implement priority queues